# Compare two columns with different values of two files and print the match without ignoring duplicates

Tags: text-processing, awk

My file1 has two columns with different values and file2 has one column with the duplicated value, however, I want to do a match of column 1 of file1 with column 1 of file2 and print the values with duplicates with column 2 of file2. Any suggestions?

file1.txt

```
YGR192C TDH3
YLR044C PDC1
YLR110C CCW12
```

file2.txt

```
YGR192C
YGR192C
YLR044C 
YLR044C
YLR110C
YLR110C
```

expected output

```
YGR192C TDH3
YGR192C TDH3
YLR044C PDC1
YLR044C PDC1
YLR110C CCW12
YLR110C CCW12
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you edit your post to include what you already tried? That way you can avoid contributors proposing solutions you already know don't work. Also, how are these files delimited? Space, Tab, combinations of those ... ?

Comment: Didn't I just answer this same question for you a couple of days ago? What happened to that question, did you delete it?

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` program should work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{key[$1]=$2;next} {$2=key[$1]}1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I'm rather sure the question is a duplicate, though ...